# Python and Django Insert Strings into a Database

Tags: python, django, database, csv

I am using Django and Python for the "framework" of a website.  What I am trying to do is create a database that stores user input.  The main purpose here is to find out the most common inputs for analytics, etc.

I thought about just making a CSV file and inserting into it via Python.  But having to open the file and write to it each time seems inefficient.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Are there any best practices out there that could help achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: You know, you can store this data into your website's db, too. If you don't want to use your main db for that, you can create a separate database solely dedicated for analytics. See Django docs on [Multiple databases](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Django you can create a model which gives you the abillity to use forms - which get displayed as a HTML form on your website.

All you now need to do is to save it. :)

To start: There's a [good tutorial at the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) especially [this part (Django: Playing with the API)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api) is interesting for you - but I recommend to start from the beginning of the tutorial first.